# Finding, counting and replacing values in lists

Tags: python-2.7, grasshopper

I am a new user, using python 2.7 with grasshopper. I have three lists (A,B,C) each with 8760 values ranging between 0 and 25000.
For each list I want to do the following.
For A to replace all the values "greater than 2000" with 2000.
For B to find the percentage of values that are between 100 and 2000.
For C to find the percentage of values greater than 300.
By percentage I mean, 'x' percent of the values in the list are greater than 'n'.
I could find such questions answered but only with somethting called numpy and panda which I don't know and can't use. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite familiar with rhino apis, and how does list work in it, but this would be the general way of doing it.

```
for x in A:
  if x > 2000:
    x = 2000

bCount = 0
for x in B:
  if x > 100 and x < 2000:
    bCount += 1

bPercentage = bCount / 8760.0

cCount = 0
for x in C:
  if x > 300:
    cCount += 1

cPercentage = cCount / 8760.0
```